# What is the proper way to deal with a recruiter who calls you on the number of your current company?

Tags: job-search, recruitment

It happened to me already the second time in the last few months that a recruiter called and asked for me on the central phone number of the company where I currently work.

Obviously, I did not leave this phone number anywhere, I guess they visited the web site of my current company and figured out the number from there. I find this extremely disrespectful that puts me in a really embarrassing situation.

My Italian boss could come to me saying: "hey, John, an unknown guy is asking for you in English" ... (thank goodness the recruiter did not say "I am from X.Y. Recruiter Company) ... and after the call even if they don't ask me who the hell it was they still obviously wait for some explanation.

I saw the question at [What is the proper way to deal with a recruiter who calls during work hours?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2732/what-is-the-proper-way-to-deal-with-a-recruiter-who-calls-during-work-hours) but I feel this case is even more serious that would require more harsh treatment.

<sup>There is a difference here, it's not just that this recruiter is calling during working hours (in that other question, they're calling the person's personal cell phone). It's that they're calling my current employer's switchboard operator/receptionist and asking for me.</sup>

How can I effectively handle recruiters calling me at my current employer's  central phone number and put a stop to it?

Comment: @MrTJ, your question has been closed as a duplicate of another question already asked on our site. If you read that question and its answer, and still have a specific unanswered question, please [edit](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/10143/edit) your question to focus it on that aspect.

Comment: There is a subtle difference here, which @MrTJ alludes to. It's not just that this recruiter is calling during working hours (in the linked post, they're calling the person's personal cell phone). It's that they're calling his **current employer's** switchboard operator/receptionist and asking for him. That's unprofessional, possibly even unethical. IMHO MrTJ should let his manager & HR department know about these calls so they can avoid dealing with those recruiters in the future.

Comment: @alroc the question currently asks - `How can I effectively handle recruiters calling me at work and put a stop to it?` - which is exactly what the linked question asks. If the focus of this question is intended to be different, MrTJ should [edit] the question as Jim says to clarify this is the focus of the question.