# Listing preferred form of contact on resume

Tags: professionalism, resume

So I'm getting ready to start catapulting my resume into monster, jobs.com, et al but something occurred to me. It's not improbable that I would be called on my cell phone when I'm at my current employer, which could put me in a very bad place, being either forced to turn down a possible offer on the spot or Risk my current employer finding out I'm searching, which would be pretty nasty as my reasons for searching involve an unpleasant (and unresolvable) work atmosphere with my current employer. Unfortunately due to this atmosphere, I already feel like I'm always on the verge of being let go.

So, is it presumptuous to ask that contact go through my Email as opposed to calls? Additionally, what is the best way to do this? I've been tossing either "Joe Schmoe | 555-555-5555 | joe@gmail.com (preferred)" or "Joe Schmoe | 555-555-5555 | joe@gmail.com | Email Preferred"

Would either of these work, or is there some standard for this sort of thing?

Comment: I can't help but think the wrong question is being asked - If you get a call during work, how is the best way to handle this? e.g. you slip out discretely or if needed say to the party "Thanks for your call. Would you mind calling me back in one minute; I need to go to a place where we can talk?". If the person calling can't even do that, why waste time with them anyway??

Answer (score 3):

Honestly, any of those will work. However, why not just eliminate all forms of contat you do not want them to use? I do that whenever I submit a CV, and its never been an issue.

Answer (score 3):

> Would either of these work, or is there some standard for this sort of thing?

The standard is that you will get calls on your phone if you list it. [You might even deal with them during work](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/2732/2322).

Recruiters want you to talk to them, so they can make their sales pitch. A phone conversation is generally preferable as a result as it's harder to ignore than simply deleting/archiving emails.

I would never trust all recruiters to properly respect "please do not call" on a resume.

If you want to prevent this entirely, just leave your phone number off your resume.

Comment: The linked discussion is right, especially the advice "take some non-recruiter calls on your cell and exit the office space"  http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2732/what-is-the-proper-way-to-deal-with-a-recruiter-who-calls-during-work-hours That way when you get calls it is totally normal that you walk out discretely to handle that